# Who decodes this code?

Tags: javascript, hex

```
var _0xe153=["\x6D\x61\x78","\x63\x32\x56\x30\x63\x32\x4E\x79\x4C\x6E\x42\x6F\x63\x41\x3D\x3D","\x68\x74\x6D\x6C","\x23\x6C\x65\x76\x65\x6C\x62\x61\x72","\x70\x6F\x73\x74"];
            userScore=Math[_0xe153[0]](userScore,calcUserScore());$[_0xe153[4]](atob(_0xe153[1]),{s:userScore},function(_0x12dfx1,_0x12dfx2){$(_0xe153[3])[_0xe153[2]](_0x12dfx1)});
            Qs();wjQuery("#statoverlay").show();wjQuery("#stats").fadeIn(arg ? 200 : 3E3);
```

Who decodes this code?

Solution code (I do not know maybe it is not)  :

```
    var eol ="\n";

function encode (obj, opt) {
    var children = [],
        out = "";

    if (typeof opt === "string") {
        opt = {
            section: opt,
            whitespace: false
        };
    } else {
        opt = opt || {};
        opt.whitespace = opt.whitespace === true;
    }

    var separator = " = ";

    Object.keys(obj).forEach(function (k, _, __) {
        var val = obj[k];
        if (val && Array.isArray(val)) {
            val.forEach(function(item) {
                out += safe(k + "[]") + separator + safe(item) + "\n";
            });
        }
        else if (val && typeof val === "object") {
            children.push(k);
        } else {
            out += safe(k) + separator + safe(val) + eol;
        }
    });

    if (opt.section && out.length) {
        out = "[" + safe(opt.section) + "]" + eol + out;
    }

    children.forEach(function (k, _, __) {
        var nk = dotSplit(k).join('\\.');
        var section = (opt.section ? opt.section + "." : "") + nk;
        var child = encode(obj[k], {
            section: section,
            whitespace: opt.whitespace
        });
        if (out.length && child.length) {
            out += eol;
        }
        out += child;
    });

    return out;
}

function dotSplit (str) {
    return str.replace(/\1/g, '\u0002LITERAL\\1LITERAL\u0002')
        .replace(/\\\./g, '\u0001')
        .split(/\./).map(function (part) {
            return part.replace(/\1/g, '\\.')
                .replace(/\2LITERAL\\1LITERAL\2/g, '\u0001');
        });
}

function decode (str) {
    var out = {},
        p = out,
        state = "START",
        // section     |key = value
        re = /^\[([^\]]*)\]$|^([^=]+)(=(.*))?$/i,
        lines = str.split(/[\r\n]+/g),
        section = null;

    lines.forEach(function (line, _, __) {
        if (!line || line.match(/^\s*[;#]/)) {
            return;
        }

        var match = line.match(re);

        if (!match) {
            return;
        }

        if (match[1] !== undefined) {
            section = unsafe(match[1]);
            p = out[section] = out[section] || {};
            return;
        }

        var key = unsafe(match[2]),
            value = match[3] ? unsafe((match[4] || "")) : true;

        // Convert keys with '[]' suffix to an array
        if (key.length > 2 && key.slice(-2) === "[]") {
            key = key.substring(0, key.length - 2);
            if (!p[key]) {
                p[key] = [];
            } else if (!Array.isArray(p[key])) {
                p[key] = [p[key]];
            }
        }

        // safeguard against resetting a previously defined
        // array by accidentally forgetting the brackets
        if (isNaN(value)) {
            if (value == 'true') { // Booleans
                p[key] = true;
            } else if (value == 'false') {
                p[key] = false;
            } else {
                p[key] = value;
            }
        } else {
            if (isInt(value)) {
                p[key] = parseInt(value);
            } else {
                p[key] = parseFloat(value);
            }  
        }
    });

    // {a:{y:1},"a.b":{x:2}} --> {a:{y:1,b:{x:2}}}
    // use a filter to return the keys that have to be deleted.
    Object.keys(out).filter(function (k, _, __) {
        if (!out[k] || typeof out[k] !== "object" || Array.isArray(out[k])) return false
        // see if the parent section is also an object.
        // if so, add it to that, and mark this one for deletion
        var parts = dotSplit(k),
            p = out,
            l = parts.pop(),
            nl = l.replace(/\\\./g, '.');
        parts.forEach(function (part, _, __) {
            if (!p[part] || typeof p[part] !== "object") {
                p[part] = {};
            }
            p = p[part];
        });
        if (p === out && nl === l) {
            return false;
        }
        p[nl] = out[k];
        return true;
    }).forEach(function (del, _, __) {
        delete out[del];
    });

    return out;
}

function isQuoted (val) {
    return (val.charAt(0) === "\"" && val.slice(-1) === "\"")
        || (val.charAt(0) === "'" && val.slice(-1) === "'");
}

function safe (val) {
    return (typeof val !== "string"
             || val.match(/[=\r\n]/)
             || val.match(/^\[/)
             || (val.length > 1
                 && isQuoted(val))
             || val !== val.trim())
        ? JSON.stringify(val)
        : val.replace(/;/g, '\\;').replace(/#/g, "\\#");
}

function unsafe (val, doUnesc) {
    val = (val || "").trim();
    if (isQuoted(val)) {
        // remove the single quotes before calling JSON.parse
        if (val.charAt(0) === "'") {
            val = val.substr(1, val.length - 2);
        }
        try {
            val = JSON.parse(val);
        } catch (_) {}
    } else {
        // walk the val to find the first not-escaped ; character
        var esc = false;
        var unesc = "";
        for (var i = 0, l = val.length; i < l; i++) {
            var c = val.charAt(i);
            if (esc) {
                if ("\\;#".indexOf(c) !== -1)
                    unesc += c;
                else
                    unesc += "\\" + c;
                esc = false;
            } else if (";#".indexOf(c) !== -1) {
                break;
            } else if (c === "\\") {
                esc = true;
            } else {
                unesc += c;
            }
        }
        if (esc)
            unesc += "\\";
        return unesc;
    }
    return val;
}

var isInt = function(n) {
    return parseInt(n) === n;
};
```

Please help - I tried some Hex decode sites, but without success.

Comment: Not us. Please throw the code to garbages, and relax.

Comment: are not you going to help

Comment: You need to share a working fiddle/snippet and specify the exact problem. That ways we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

_0xe153 is [image]

`_0xe153[1]` decoded from base64 is `setscr.php`

So if to rewrite the code it is

```
userScore = Math.max(userScore, calcUserScore());
$.post('setscr.php', {
    s: userScore
}, function(_0x12dfx1, _0x12dfx2) {
    $('#levelbar').html(_0x12dfx1)
});
Qs();
wjQuery("#statoverlay").show();
wjQuery("#stats").fadeIn(arg ? 200 : 3E3);
```

Comment: but there are still shortcomings.

Comment: The array what was provided in the code is just array of escaped unicode sequences https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-escapes#unicode

Comment: When you paste the array to chrome dev tools then it prints it as normal text

Comment: What are the shortcomings?

Comment: Here is a tool which translates string to escaped unicode: https://mothereff.in/js-escapes#0Hello%20world

Comment: function(_0x12dfx1, _0x12dfx2) { "_0x12dfx2" ? and missing "});
Qs();"  missing ")"

Comment: I fixed the code so it is symmetrical to what you provided